# Monotouch and Xcode 4 - How to Open XIB in Xcode 3

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xib

I just installed Xcode 4 and found I can't edit XIBs yet from MonoTouch.

How do I get MonoTouch to open my XIBs with the old Interface builder?

When I right click I get "Open With" but the old UI Builder is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install Xcode3 somewhere as well, I personally use /Xcode3

Comment: Why did this get checked as the solution as it doesn't solve the problem just installing Xcode 3 to someplace else? This doesn't fix the problem.  I have Xcode 4 in the default Developer folder and then installed Xcode 3 in Developer3 folder.  MonoDevelop is still opening XIB's in Xcode 4, there is no Open With options added to change this, and no options to tell MonoDevelop/MonoTouch where IB is in the UI.  Is there a plist that MonoTouch uses for pointing to IB?

Comment: You have to pick a .xib in Finder (any will do) and hit Command+I on it.  If you have both Xcode4 and Xcode3 installed, in the Open With disclosure panel you can change it to "Interface Builder" and click "Change all" to make this the default association.  If you had a follow up question, you could have just asked for clarification btw, I'd be happy to provide even without the downvote.